# Conditional comments for CSS in IE9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

I want to add a specific style sheet for IE9 which overrides the img.icon css class with different margin values. So i add the below in the head section. But when page loads it display as a text in browser.

```
 <!--[if IE 9]>
    img.icon {
        float: right;
        margin: 4px -31px;
    }
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `<style>` tags

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
    img.icon {
        float: right;
        margin: 4px -31px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--[if IE9]>
<style>
    img.icon {
        float: right;
        margin: 4px -31px;
    }
</style>
    <![endif]-->
```

it think

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the style tags.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
    img.icon {
        float: right;
        margin: 4px -31px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, you might find it easier to load an external stylesheet within the conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css">
<![endif]-->
```